# How do I make a simple snapshot webapp in HTML5?

Tags: html, web-applications, camera, webcam, snapshot

I need to make a HTML5 page that can display live video coming from the device's camera/webcam and that has a button that can take a snapshot; nothing fancy (similar to html5camera.com). I tried following some tutorials (http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/ AND  http://davidwalsh.name/browser-camera), but I'm still new at HTML, so I'm not sure what to do with the code snippets I find.

I copied some code into a HTML-file, but when I open it with Chrome, it says at the right in the address bar that it blocked access to the camera and microphone (without bothering to ask for permission). When I click the option to ask for permission next time and reload the page, nothing happens. There is no way to set the preferences to allow by default. I also tried Chrome Canary (same as Chrome) and Firefox (didn't ask for permission).

**Did I make a mistake in the HTML? Is Chrome the problem?**

The code I have so far:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=yes">
    </head>
    <body>
        <video id="video" width="640" height="480" autoplay></video>
        <button id="snap">Snap Photo</button>
        <canvas id="canvas" width="640" height="480"></canvas>
        <script>
            // Put event listeners into place
            window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
                // Grab elements, create settings, etc.
                var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
                    context = canvas.getContext("2d"),
                    video = document.getElementById("video"),
                    videoObj = { "video": true },
                    errBack = function(error) {
                        console.log("Video capture error: ", error.code); 
                    };
                // Put video listeners into place
                if(navigator.getUserMedia) { // Standard
                    navigator.getUserMedia(videoObj, function(stream) {
                        video.src = stream;
                        video.play();
                    }, errBack);
                } else if(navigator.webkitGetUserMedia) { // WebKit-prefixed
                    navigator.webkitGetUserMedia(videoObj, function(stream){
                        video.src = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(stream);
                        video.play();
                    }, errBack);
                }
                // Trigger photo take
                document.getElementById("snap").addEventListener("click", function() {
                    context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, 640, 480);
                });
            }, false);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might also consider just going native. You can add native camera and camcorder support to any web app on Android, iOS or Windows Phone 8 very easily with BridgeIt: http://bridgeit.mobi. It's a simple javascript api that allows you to access native mobile features.